# Selecting a user to confirm a deletion (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

Good morning,

I want to create a dialog box that asks me to confirm the deletion of a user but I can't specify the right user, when I click on "delete" it tries to delete the first user from my table.

**Users/index.blade.php**

```html
@section('tableHeader')
    <th class="align-middle">ID</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Avatar</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Pseudo</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Nom et Prénom</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Age</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Email</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Date D'Inscription</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Actions</th>
@endsection

@section('tableData')
    @foreach($users as $user)
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Supprimer {{ $user->pseudo }} ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <a href="{{ route('adminUserDestroy' , $user->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">
                <img src="{{ asset( 'storage/' . $user->avatar ) }}" height="50" width="50">
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->pseudo }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->lastName }} {{ $user->firstName }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->age }} ans</td>
            <td class="align-middle" style="max-width: 14vw; overflow: scroll; overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;">{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle" style="min-width: 12vw">
                <a href="{{ route('adminUserShow' , $user->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1">Voir Plus</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Supprimer</button>
                {{--                <a href="{{ route('adminUserDestroy' , $user->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button></a>--}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endsection

@section('paginate')
    {{ $users->links() }}
@endsection
```

I can't wait to see your answers! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated to your need

How this works is you don't use bootstrap's `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"`

You add custom data attribute something like `data-user-id="{{ $user->id }}"`

Also move the modal outside of the loop. Use single modal and set user id using jquery.

Example:

```php
<button data-user-id="{{ $user->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger deleteUser">Supprimer</button>
```

added `deleteUser` class to apply jquery click event on it.

Then on you pick the user id on jquery and assign anywhere you want to assign

Example:

```
$('.deleteUser').click(function(){
   let userID = $(this).data('user-id');

   // use the userId and assign it
   // add id="deleteBtn" to your delete button as well
   let deleteURL = "{{ route('adminUserDestroy' , ':id') }}";
   deleteURL = deleteURL.replace(':id', userID);
   $('#deleteBtn').attr('href', deleteURL);

   $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); // this will open the modal.
})
```

Comment: You can place this userId into your modal or pass though ajax.
As you like to send it to your controller totally upto you.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are doing is rendering a modal per entry in your `$user` collection:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <!-- Create a modal -->
@endforeach
```

But each modal has the same id `exampleModal`. So no matter which button you click on, it will pick the first modal with that `id` that it finds in the `DOM`.

Try using a single modal with `data` properties injected by the button when it is clicked. (see Akhzar Javed's answer)

Comment: If people are going to downvote an answer, please provide a reason for doing so. I am more than willing to update or remove my answer if you believe it to be wrong.